# Reading quoted string in c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to read quoted string from a file and store it in string. I am reading string from the file and input file is like this:

```
"Rigatoni" starch 2.99
"Mac & Cheese" starch 0.50
"Potato Salad" starch 3.59
"Fudge Brownie" sweet 4.99
"Sugar Cookie" sweet 1.50
```

I have tried to do couple things:

1.

```
input.open(filename);
    if (input.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "File is not found!";
        exit(1);
    }   
    else
    {    
        std::string foodName = ""; std::string foodType = "";
        double cost;
        input >> foodName >> foodType >> cost;
        foodName = foodName.substr(1, foodName.size()-2);    
        std::cout << foodName << " " << foodType << " " << cost << std::endl;
    }


    input.close();
```

This version works only for the first line. After first line I am not getting whole quoted word. Another version reads whole quoted word, however, following word and number are separated.

```
input.open(filename);
        if (input.fail())
        {
            std::cout << "File is not found!";
            exit(1);
        }   
        else
        {


            std::string line = "";
            while (std::getline(input, line, '\n')) //delimeter is new line
            {
                if (line != "")
                {
                    std::stringstream stream(line);
                    std::string foodName = "";
                    while (std::getline(stream, foodName, '"') ) //delimeter is double quotes
                    {                   
                        std::cout << "current word " << foodName << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }   input.close();
```

My goal is to read 3 separate words. I looked over other similar topics in stackoverflow but could not find the  right solution for my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I often use this to read between quotes:

```
std::string skip; // throw this away
std::string foodName;
std::getline(std::getline(input, skip, '"'), foodName, '"');
```

The first [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) reads up to (and removes) the first quote. It returns the input stream so you can wrap that in another [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) that reads in your variable up to the closing quote.

For example like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::istringstream input(R"~(
"Rigatoni" starch 2.99
"Mac & Cheese" starch 0.50
"Potato Salad" starch 3.59
"Fudge Brownie" sweet 4.99
"Sugar Cookie" sweet 1.50
)~");

int main()
{
    std::string skip; // dummy
    std::string foodName;
    std::string foodType;
    float foodValue;

    while(std::getline(std::getline(input, skip, '"'), foodName, '"') >> foodType >> foodValue)
    {
        std::cout << "food : " << foodName << '\n';
        std::cout << "type : " << foodType << '\n';
        std::cout << "value: " << foodValue << '\n';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
food : Rigatoni
type : starch
value: 2.99

food : Mac & Cheese
type : starch
value: 0.5

food : Potato Salad
type : starch
value: 3.59

food : Fudge Brownie
type : sweet
value: 4.99

food : Sugar Cookie
type : sweet
value: 1.5
```

Comment: Thanks @Galik, that`s what I am looking for.

Answer (score 18):

This becomes trivial with C++14's [`std::quoted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted):

```
#include <iomanip>
std::string foodName, foodType;
double cost;
while (fs >> std::quoted(foodName) >> foodType >> cost)
{
}
```

Yes, this will correctly parse `"some word"` into `some word`. Don't have a C++14 capable compiler? (You should, Fedora 22 ships with GCC 5.1.0 for example) then use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/io/doc/quoted_manip.html). The standard library modelled `std::quoted` after this Boost component, so it should work just as fine.

There are some other problems in your code:

1. Streams have a conversion operator to bool. This means you can do: `if (!input.open(filename)) { ... }`
2. `input.close()` is redundant. The destructor will automatically close the stream.
3. You don't check if the input is valid, i.e. `if (!(input >> a >> b >> c)) { // error }`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am required to use C++07/TR1. But your method is easy to use.

Comment: is there a standard escape sequence for quoted strings that contain double-quotes (e.g. two double quotes, "She said, ""Hello!""")?

Comment: Nice, +1! Learned something new today (`std::quoted`).

Comment: @franji1 Don't know what you mean, but it correctly handles nested quotes. In general, it's meant to be similar to a CSV parser.

Comment: @franji1 In your case, modify the example to: `std::getline(std::cin, s); std::cout << std::quoted(s);` The output is `"\"She said, \"\"Hello!\"\"\""` I pasted your input literally.

Comment: @Zafar If you don't have `std::quoted` available, and don't want to use Boost, it is pretty trivial to just write your own `operator<<` overload to handle reading/writing of quoted strings.