# How to remove duplicate phrases that are separated by being inside double quotes or separated by a comma in a file with c++

Tags: c++

I use this function to remove duplicate words in a file
But I need it to remove duplicate expressions instead

for example What the function is currently doing
     If I have the expression
     "Hello World"
     "beautiful world"
The function will remove the word "world" from both expressions

And I need this function to replace the entire expression only if it is found more than once in the file
for example

If I have the expressions
"Hello World"
"Hello World"
"beautiful world"
"beautiful world"

The function will remove the expression "Hello world" and "beautiful world" and leave only one from each of them but it will not touch the word "world" because the function will treat everything that is within the quotes as one word

This is the code I use now

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

void Remove_Duplicate_Words(string str)
{
ofstream Write_to_file{ "test.txt" };

// Used to split string around spaces. 
istringstream ss(str);

// To store individual visited words 
unordered_set<string> hsh;

// Traverse through all words 
do
{
    string word;
    ss >> word;

    // If current word is not seen before. 
    while (hsh.find(word) == hsh.end()) {
        cout << word << '\n';
        Write_to_file << word << endl; // write to outfile 
        hsh.insert(word);
    }

} while (ss);
}


int main()
{
    ifstream Read_from_file{ "test.txt" };
    string file_content{ ist {Read_from_file}, ist{} };

    Remove_Duplicate_Words(file_content);

return 0;
}
```

How do I remove duplicate expressions instead of duplicate words?

Unfortunately my knowledge on this subject is very basic and usually what I do is try all kinds of things until I succeed. I tried to do it here too and I just can not figure out how to do it
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you define a phrase?

Comment: @user4581301: or "what's the difference between word and phrase?"

Comment: Are phrases on separate lines or is there any specific delimiter between them? Otherwise will be almost impossible.

Comment: A word is one word
A phrase is a few words that together constitute a sentence
And for the function to recognize that this is an phrase I put this phrase in quotation marks Or separating them with a comma

Comment: If the function could remove duplicate lines instead of duplicate words, it would also be good. In other words, if the function detects that the group of words is an expression because it is in a separate line and then removes duplicate lines then that too will be good

Comment: Duplicate lines would be relatively easy using `std::getline` to read lines instead of `>>` which reads whitespace-delimited tokens (AKA words). Looking for quote-wrapped phrases requires smarter parsing. You find the first quote, you find the next quote, and you store everything between. You may have to watch out for stuff like "You had me at "Hello."". Note that equality between strings is exact. "Hello world" is not the same as "Hello World". You may also have to handle this. Converting the strings to lower case before comparing and then storing the original often helps here.

Comment: The problem is explaining to the computer where a phrase or expression starts and ends. Humans can do it quite easily, but a machine cannot. You need to define some rule and be sure that the input file follows that rule. One expression per line is easy to handle for example. Or you can use a dot `.` at the end of each expression. This is a rule you need to choose before writing the code, and then adhere to it.

Comment: Removing duplicate lines instead of duplicate words will also work well for me
I tried to use the std::getline instead of find(word) And it did not work
Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Show what you tried with `getline`. Odds are good someone will spot what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requires a little bit of String parsing.

Your example works by reading tokens, which are similar to words (but not exactly). For your problem, the token becomes word OR quoted string. The more complex your definition of tokens, the harder the problem becomes. Try starting by thinking of tokens as either words or quoted strings on the same line. A quoted string across lines might be a little more complex.

Here's a similar SO question to get you started: [Reading quoted string in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072293/reading-quoted-string-in-c). You need to do something similar, but instead of having set positions, your quoted string can occur anywhere in the line. So you read tokens something like this:

1. Read next word token (as you're doing now)
2. If last read token is quote character ("), read till next (") as a single token
3. Check on the set and output token only if it isn't already there (if token is quoted, don't forget to output the quotes)
4. Insert token into set.
5. Repeat till EOF

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks man but it's too complicated for my level of programming knowledge
From what I understood the easiest and uncomplicated way is to remove lines instead of words so I prefer to remove lines. The only question is how to convert the function from replacing duplicate words to replacing duplicate rows?

Comment: Duplicate rows are much simpler than looking for quoted strings. Instead of using extractor operator `>>`, you can use getline. So `ss >> word` becomes `getline(ss, word)`.

Comment: Thanks man. It works like magic. And after you showed me exactly where to put this `getline(ss, word)` I took `getline(getline(ss, skip, '"'), word, '"')` from the link you gave me and put it in the same place and it removes duplicate phrases only within a double quote as I wanted from the beginning. Thank you very much Raze you are the best

Comment: Happy to help! I'm glad that you didn't give up and kept working on it.